# Using a C++ map to count word frequency. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++, dictionary

So  a little background. I am supposed to make a program that goes through a paragraph, line by line and picks out the most frequently used word on each line. I have effectively written code that stores the contents of a line in a vector, now i need to assign the frequncey to these words. I am using a map, but it isnt giving me the desired outcome. I am new to C++ data structures, so some advice would be appreciated.

```
map<string,int> freq;   //map for getting frequency on line

    for(int i=0;i<currLine.size();i++){   //loops through the words on the line


        string currName=currLine.at(i);  //current word
        //cout<<currName<<endl;
        if(freq.find(currName)!=freq.end()){   //if already present

                int update=freq.at(currName)+1;  //this value takes the value and adds one
                freq.insert(pair<string,int>(currName,update));  //insert back into the string with updated value
                //cout<<freq.at(currName);
        }
        else{
            freq.insert(pair<string,int>(currName,0)); //if not present, then insert with value 0
        }
    }
```

For Example:

-Unlike you I take umbrage with gnu.
Don’t mind me taking the food with me?
George Orwell was wrong about 1984.
Can your cat code? If not, can your dog code?
I like to play the fallout games. Recommend you play it as well.
Soccer is the most popular sport outside America.

Would return: "unlike me george can play soccer"

```
    int main()
{
    string line;
    vector<string> result;
    while(getline(cin,line)){     //on each line
        vector<string> currLine;  //stores words on line
        string curr="";  //temp string for grasping words
        for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++){  //loops through line
            if(isalpha(line.at(i))){  //if it is a letter, add it to the temp string
                curr+=tolower(line.at(i));
            }
            else if(line.at(i)=='\''){
                    //do nothing
            }
            else{    //if not, then add the previous word to vector and reset temp string
                currLine.push_back(curr);
                curr="";
            }
        }



        vector< pair<string, int> > freq(10);
        //freq.push_back(make_pair("asd",2));
        for(int i=0;i<currLine.size();i++){
            string curr1=currLine.at(i);
            cout<<curr1<<" ";
            for(int j=0;j<freq.size();j++){
                if(freq.at(j).first==curr1){  //if present in the list
                    //cout<<"Duplicate found";
                    freq.at(j).second++;     //increment second value
                }
                else{
                    //cout<<"Pair Made";
                    freq.push_back(make_pair(curr1,1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        int max=0;
        string currMost;
        for(int i =0;i<freq.size();i++){

            if(freq.at(i).second>max){
                max=freq.at(i).second;;
                currMost=freq.at(i).first;
            }
        }
        //cout<<currMost;

        cout<<endl;



       // result.push_back(currMost);

    }

    for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        cout<<result.at(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: What output do you get, what do you expect, what is your input?

Comment: Why not just `string currName = currLine.at(i); ++freq[currName];`?

Comment: I get a paragraph and the most commonly used word on each line is the relevant word in the cipher

Comment: @melpomene what does that do? I am in an intro C++ class so i am using my java knowledge for most of this stuff

Comment: `++` and `[]` exist in Java.

Comment: You should insert with value 1.

Comment: Are you storing words or letters?

Comment: At this point in the program i am counting how many times a certain word occurs in the line

Comment: @Team.Coco:  `freq[currName]` will find the entry in `freq` for `currName`.  If it doesn't exist, it will insert it with the default value (zero in the case of a int).  I usually find this behaviour annoying, but in this case, it is *exactly* what you want.  A reference to the found element is returned.  The `++` then increments it.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  Note that this means a *complete* small program which shows your problem (*not* your actual program - which will have lots of extraneous junk in it).  You also need to tell us what output you expect, and what you are getting.

Comment: Hang on:  Why is `freq` not a map?

Comment: We havent learned about maps yet. If i used a map, i wouldnt know how to get the key if i was trying to find the sting that was most used. I know it sounds dumb, but i just dont know it haha

Comment: @Team.Coco Then why does your original question use `map<string,int> freq;`?

Comment: This is my thought process. I want the string to represent the word that is being used and the int to represnt how many times it has been used. But what i have learned is that getting the key of a map is near impossible

Comment: Map `insert` fails if the entry is already present; instead you should update the existing entry.  (Not sure if this is your only problem, it just stood out to me on a quick read)

Comment: So, you know the concept of a map because you studied it in java, but you haven't learned yet any about them in C++. I'm wondering if are allowed or not to use that container for this task.

Comment: And when using arbitrary containers is allowed, `multiset` and its `count` member would be a better fit for the problem anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I first split the sentence into words and then store them into map. The easiest and more obvious way for map insertion is to use `map[key] = value` notation. I checked first whether the value is already present by using `count()` function and insert the value, otherwise I incremented the already present key's value.

```
map <string, int> word_frequency;
string word="";
for (int i=0; i<=current_line.length();i++) {
    if (current_line[i]!=' ' && i< current_line.length()) {
        word = word + current_line[i];
    } else if(word_frequency.count(word) == 0) {
       word_frequency[word] = 1;
       word = "";
    } else {
        word_frequency[word]++;
        word = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking whether `word` is/is not in the map (`if(word_frequency.count(word) == 0) ...`) is unnecessary.  Operator[] will insert it if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually some good ways to make your solution easier to implement (at least conceptually).

Read a paragraph line by line. For each line read, there will be some lexems separated by delimiter (i guess it's the trickiest part, since they can be various, like `'.' / ',' / ' '`). For sake of simplicity let's assume that it can be only one of those, say space.
After that, for each line, you would want to split it somehow. There's actually a `boost::split` method that does just like that, but you can also use `getline` and `stringstream` object, which lets string behave somwhat like `stdin`. Then, foe revery splitted word, you can simply increment it's value since if the key is not in map, it will hold the value of zero. So just `++` it.
Overall, it should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>


int main(void)    {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t> freq;
    std::string input;
    std::string word;

    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);      // behaves like dup, substitute your STDIN
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);    // same, but with STDOUT

    while (getline(std::cin, input))    {     // read whole line
        freq.clear();                         // clear data in map for new line
        std::istringstream ss(input);          // initialize string stream
        while(std::getline(ss, word, ' ')) {   // split by spaces
            ++freq[word];                      // count the amount of seen
        }
        // Your way to sort map here //
    }
```