# How to get the most frequent element of a list?

Tags: c++, list, element

Let's say I have a list:

`std::list<std::string> list ("the", "the", "friend", "hello", "the");`

In this case, the most common element in the list is `"the"`. Is there a way to get this element in C++??

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is. Did you attempt anything yourself yet?

Comment: Don't know of a library function to do it, but it's pretty easy to write.

Comment: `std::map` might help

Comment: @user2079303, I could attempt a `for` loop that counts every time that that word is in the list, and then return the most frequent word. Though this method is not really efficient, I was seeking for a better solution.

Comment: If this is one of those annoying homework problems where you can't use the most natural tool (a hash table) -- you could sort the list and then determine what you want in a single pass over the sorted lists.

Comment: Dat Ha, you are quite close with the loop, but look into the possibilities offered by @JohnColeman 's suggestion.

Comment: I'm really not convinced of the relevance of this question to "artificial-intelligence". Please don't spam tags.

Comment: [Are lists evil?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#list)

Comment: @JohnColeman Look, here is the simple truth. I am trying to build a simple word learning AI and I what that when I input a big text, such as a paragraph from a book, My AI can determine a couple of stuff, Including the most frequent word. This is not homework related. In fact, I am just in high school and we just do Arduinos.

Comment: Then why the fixation on `list`? There are much better suited data structures and a large part of the programmer's job is to select the best structure. Tempted to say that the rest of the job is pretty much selecting the right algorithm and typing, but that denigrates debugging.

Comment: @DatHa Sounds like a fun project. The reference to homework was due to the fact that you said that "I will use `list` and nothing else." That sounded like a restriction that a professor might make. If you aren't *required* to use lists, why restrict yourself to them? Dictionaries (aka maps or hashes) are by far the best data structure for this sort of thing. With a map you can determine what you want in `O(n)`, but I don't think you can get any better than `O(nlog(n))` sticking to lists.

Comment: If you want to experiment with `map`, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39314633/4996248

Comment: @JohnColeman : What about simply using vector as my main container??

Comment: @DatHa  vectors are probably better general purpose containers than lists. See this: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185222/what-is-the-point-of-using-lists-over-vectors-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general algorithm to solve your problem is to build a dictionary of word frequencies. Here is a pseudo code algorithm, that does exactly that:

```
let L be the input sequence of strings (can be a list, doesn't matter)
let F be an empty dictionary that maps string to a number
for each string S in L
    if not F contains S then
        F[S] = 0
    F[S] += 1
```

Once the dictionary is constructed, all you need to do is to find the mapping with the highest value, and return the key.

The C++ standard library provides associative containers (aka dictionaries, aka *maps*), and an algorithm for searching for the greatest element within a container.